# What is the difference between partitions & available partitions for topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am planning to write my own `Partitioner` for Kafka Producer, so I was seeing the implementation of Kafka's [DefaultPartitioner](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java).

I saw that it calls Cluster's `availablePartitionsForTopic` and sometimes calls `partitionsForTopic` for computing partition.

I read the documentation & also saw the source code, but I am not able to see what is the difference between the two.

Can someone point me to the right documentation for this or explain the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specify a key for a record, Kafka probably thinks you definitely want this record to be sent to some determined partition even if it is not available at that time.

However, if no key is specified, then Kafka might think you care nothing about the target partition the record goes to, so it picks up one randomly from those "alive" partitions.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question *difference between* `partitionsForTopic`and `availablePartitionsForTopic` (not how `DefaultPartitioner` uses them to assign a Partition), code is the only documentation

Have a look at `org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster`,

```
    this.partitionsByTopic = new HashMap<>(partsForTopic.size());
    this.availablePartitionsByTopic = new HashMap<>(partsForTopic.size());
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<PartitionInfo>> entry : partsForTopic.entrySet()) {
        String topic = entry.getKey();
        List<PartitionInfo> partitionList = entry.getValue();
        this.partitionsByTopic.put(topic, Collections.unmodifiableList(partitionList));
        List<PartitionInfo> availablePartitions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PartitionInfo part : partitionList) {
            if (part.leader() != null)
                availablePartitions.add(part);
            }
        this.availablePartitionsByTopic.put(topic, Collections.unmodifiableList(availablePartitions));
    }
```

As you can see, the distinguishing factor between the two is the availability of a leader